# How to access a virtual machine hosted by VMWare ESXi from an external IP?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware, esxi

There is a network topology as follows:

[image: VMWare ESXi 6.7 Host Network]

I can access both 172.16.0.10:8444 and 172.16.0.21:8445 from the external IP by:

```
telnet A 8444
telnet A 8445
```

However, I can not access 172.16.0.20:8443 by:

```
telnet A 8443 # connection timeout
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can try to troubleshoot the issue as below:

**Step 1.** Can we ping 172.16.0.20 on Windows server 2016?

If we can't ping, check the network configuration of Virtual machine Ubuntu 18.04.

If we can ping, continue with step 2.

**Step 2.** Can we telnet 172.16.0.20 on port 8443 on Windows server 2016?

If we can not telnet, check the firewall and IPtables on Virtual machine Ubuntu 18.04 and if the service corresponding to 8443 is running?

If we can telnet, continue with step 3.

**Step 3.** Check that if the configuration of the 8443 Port Mapping on the Router is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Step 1 and Step 2: Yes.

Step 3: Port Mapping of  172.16.0.20 is same as 172.16.0.21. I have tried to set 172.16.0.20 as the DMZ of the Router, but it did not work either.